# I'm new to web dev. So i have this project I'm doing and tried running the npm install command but it could'nt install sqlite3

Tags: node.js, node-sqlite3

The commandline threw up a lot of errors but these were the bottom errors. Any help

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.13 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17403678/5605822

Comment: Do you have gcc+, make and python2.7 installed?

Comment: [sqlite3 on npmjs.com - Installing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#installing)

Comment: I dont have gcc+ installed. I'll try that first